# how to know iOS firebase crash report upload complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-crash-reporting

I used Firebase Crash Report in iOS project. My project hybrid web so needs Crashes Clear.

Tried :

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

but It was not as efficient as I thought.

So changed to

```
NSString *LibraryDir = [NSString stringWithString:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"]];
NSString *Library_CachesDir = [NSString stringWithString:[LibraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches"]];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *list = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:Library_CachesDir error:nil];

if ([list count]!=0)
{
    for (NSString *path in [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:Library_CachesDir error:nil])
    {
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[Library_CachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:path] error:nil];
    }
}
```

This source is perfectly clear. However this source deletes all including Firebases crash report.
So I want when upload firebase crash report successful time.
firebase crash report upload next
clear cache function.

If you know any other methods, please recommend.

Have a nice day.